# rtcwake not executed as root cron job

Tags: linux, cron

This `rtcwake` job launched manually works fine :

```
$ sudo rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 07:30')
```

but doesn't seem to run as a `root` cron job :

```
$ sudo crontab -l
32 7 * * * rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 07:30')
```

If I log the command with

```
$ sudo crontab -l
32 7 * * * rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 07:30') &> /home/me/path/to/dir/crond.log
```

I get an empty log file. *And the owner of `crond.log` is me, not `root`. (**EDIT 1:** this not the case, my mistake with several tests)*.

What exactly is the issue here?

***EDIT 2 :** thanks to @αғsнιη answer, the correct cronjob is the following (created with `sudo crontab -e`):*

```
$ sudo crontab -l
32 7 * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m no -u -t $(date +\%s -d 'tomorrow 07:30') &> /home/me/path/to/dir/crond.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things about your cronjob:

1. `%` should be escaped `\%` because that's special character for crontab and means a newline.
2. always write commands with thier full/absolute path, since crontab doesn't read your shell's `PATH` variable.