# How to run the `rtcwake` within `crontab`?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, suspend

I tried to run the `rtcwake` as root and it's working:

```
root@ywt01-15Z90N-V-AR53C2:~# rtcwake -m mem -s 90
```

↑ This command is working.

But When I tried to run the `rtcwake` within `crontab`, it's not working:

1. open `crontab`:

   ```
    root@ywt01-15Z90N-V-AR53C2:~# crontab -e
   ```
2. edit `crontab`:

   ```
    01 22 * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -s 90 > /root/rtc.log 2>$1
   ```

What should I change in the above steps?  Or am I missing some other steps?

PS. My OS info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: `2>$1` should likely be `2>&1` ... then check `/root/rtc.log` for any error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how to fix your `rtcwake` script – there's multiple things that feel a bit anachronistic about that :)

Instead, systemd (as your Ubuntu 20.04 is based on!) makes it simple to have a timer task for which the system is woken up automatically. Something like https://joeyh.name/blog/entry/a_programmable_alarm_clock_using_systemd/ :

/etc/systedm/system/whatever_I_need_to_do_at_22_01.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Important thing that needs to happen 1 past 10
RefuseManualStop=true
RefuseManualStart=true
# Requires=multi-user.target or whatever you want to sure runs!
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/true
```

/etc/systedm/system/whatever_I_need_to_do_at_22_01.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Important timer

[Timer]
Unit=whatever_I_need_to_do_at_22_01.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 22:01
WakeSystem=true
Persistent=false 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You then just `sudo systemctl enable --now whatever_I_need_to_do_at_22_01.timer` to enable waking up at the specified time.

To go to sleep, use `systemctl suspend`. You can also have a timer that invokes the `systemd-suspend.service` if you want to suspend at any given time!

Answer (score 1):

See this thread ([rtcwake not executed as root cron job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692754/rtcwake-not-executed-as-root-cron-job)) for an answer using `rtcwake`.  In my case, I had to add `sudo` to the `cron` command, even though I'm using `root`'s cron:

```
30 14 * * * sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'today 17:55:00') >> /home/user/crond.log 2>&1
```

Modifying `systemd` seems like overkill.